# Memory Issue When Accessing Multidimensional Array Index

Tags: objective-c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've allocated a mutable array as:

```
self.allisonHall.hours = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:7];
```

and filled it with data:

```
self.allisonHall.hours = @[
                           @[
                               @[@600,@780],
                               @[@1005,@1170]
                           ],
                           @[
                               @[@450,@585],
                               @[@705,@795],
                               @[@1005,@1140]
                           ],
                           @[
                               @[@450,@585],
                               @[@705,@795],
                               @[@1005,@1140]
                           ],
                           @[
                               @[@450,@585],
                               @[@705,@795],
                               @[@1005,@1140]
                           ],
                           @[
                               @[@450,@585],
                               @[@705,@795],
                               @[@1005,@1140]
                           ],
                           @[
                               @[@450,@585],
                               @[@705,@795],
                               @[@1005,@1140]
                           ],
                           @[
                               @[@645,@810],
                               @[@1005,@1170]
                           ],
                        ];
```

When I attempt to access an element using the code
    int open = _hours[0][i][0];

or

```
int open = _hours[0][i][1];
```

where i is 2 or 3 (depending on the number of objects in each of the 7 parent arrays, open is assigned as 146980960, clearly a memory address. When debugging, the command

```
po open
```

results in 600, 450, etc.—all correct values of the array.
However, when I'm performing inequalities later in the function, they do not resolve as expected because open is 146980960 within the scope.

Why does "po" print the variable as expected while it does not exist this way in the function?
And how can I resolve it?

Thanks

Comment: You haven't allocated an array and filled it with data, you've allocated an array, then replaced it with a different array, letting the original one go out of scope and get released.

Comment: If I simply change the allocation to `[[NSArray alloc] init]` then fill it with data will the same problem occur? Or is it necessary to initialize the array with the data?

Comment: You don't need to allocate or initialize _anything_. The `@[…]` creates an array. Just assign that directly to your `NSArray *` variable; don't assign something else (an empty array or otherwise) to that variable just to overwrite it a moment later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting a pointer rather than the value is because you are passing a `NSNumber` rather than the actual value into the array. In other words, `open` should be a `NSNumber` and you can use one of its methods such as `intValue` to get the actual value. Hope this helped!

Comment: That solved it. Thanks! Still getting a handle on Objective-C.